# How to add weights for records to find to most matching results

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm developing a web application using ASP.net web forms C# and SQL service for the database. I've three main tables:

```
Services: ( more than 10K records)

Service_Id      Service_Description 
 1               Clean
 2               Oil Change
 3               Fluid Services
 4               Filter Replacement
```

the other table for customer requests

```
Customer_Requests:
Customer_ResuestId      Customer_RequstedServices 
 1                      1
 1                      2
 1                      3
 1                      4
 2                      4
 2                      5
```

the third main table is branches ( I've like 500 branches; each branch offers specific services )

```
Branches:
Branch_Id      Branch_AvailabeServices 
 1               1
 1               2
 1               3
 2               1
 2               2
 2               3
 2               4
```

My question, How can I add weights for each Customer_RequstedServices and to find to most matching results. For example, I want the results to be something like that:

**Customer request #1**

has **4** service requests ( **25% for each request** )

**Branch #2** offers **100%** of his requests, and **Branch #1** offers **75%** of his requests.

I want to show branch #2 at first as it offers all customers requirements.

I was able to get the weight by using:

```
Select count(Customer_ResuestId) as ServiceCount from Customer_Requests
```

then I can do 100/ServiceCount to get the weights for each record.

but I do not know how can I find that what services can be offered by each branch for each specific request..

Any help would be really appreciated. If the weights something that can not/difficult to be measured, then finding the branch the offers the most requested service would be really great and acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT 
    Customer_ResuestId, 
    (Select Count(*) From Customer_Requests AS CRc 
        WHERE CR.Customer_ResuestId= CRC.Customer_ResuestId) as RequestedServices,
    Branch_Id, 
    Count(*) as MatchingServicesOffered 
FROM CustomerRequests CR 
INNER JOIN Branches B 
    ON B.Branch_AvailabeServices = CR.Customer_RequstedServices 
GROUP BY Customer_ResuestId, 
    Branch_Id 
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been testing this code for two days with real data. and It works perfectly as needed! God bless you!